# Python: indentation error, methods in different order

Tags: python

I am getting this python indentation error which I don't understand

I have two versions of code which is actually exactly the same but in different order. One works but the other doesn't. I don't know why.

This is the version that doesn't work:

> Error message: "File "/Users/HonghuiChoi/Desktop/helloworld/main.py",
>   line 28
>       def get(self):
>                    ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.write(form % {"error":error})

    def get(self): #THIS IS THE LINE THAT COMPLAINS
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("invalid date!")
        else:
            self.response.write("valid day.")
```

And this is the version that works:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def write_form(self, error=""):
        self.response.write(form % {"error":error})

    def post(self):
        user_month = valid_month(self.request.get('month'))
        user_day = valid_day(self.request.get('day'))
        user_year = valid_year(self.request.get('year'))

        if not (user_month and user_day and user_year):
            self.write_form("invalid date!")
        else:
            self.response.write("valid day.")
```

Comment: Did you check for a mixture of spaces and tab characters in the indents?

Comment: This is so weird. The version that used to work doesn't even work anymore. I didn't use spaces, I only used tabs to indent.

Comment: Then try replacing all your tabs with spaces. Everything I have read strongly recommends avoiding tab characters for indents.

Comment: I used tabs and it works now, but I will try to avoid using tabs from now on. I think a mixture of spaces and tabs messed everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I look at your code, as entered in your question, you have a mixture of spaces and tab characters in your indents.

Copying your code, and adding the extra indent to show code, may have changed these things, but you definitely need to check that carefully in your original code.  The Python tutorial (IIRC), together with other documentation, strongly recommends using only spaces. Try replacing all tabs with spaces.

**ADDED:** I now see that I was recalling [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) rather than the Python tutorial. PEP 8 says

> Spaces are the preferred indentation method.
>
> Tabs should be used solely to remain consistent with code that is
>   already indented with tabs.
>
> Python 3 disallows mixing the use of tabs and spaces for indentation.
>
> Python 2 code indented with a mixture of tabs and spaces should be
>   converted to using spaces exclusively.
>
> When invoking the Python 2 command line interpreter with the  -t
>   option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and
>   spaces. When using  -tt   these warnings become errors. These options
>   are highly recommended!

Comment: You are right. I looked like every line of code was in line. But after shifting every line to the left and then using tabs to indent, it works no matter what order they are in.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: One quick question, how did you know my code contained a mixture of tabs and spaces by just looking at it? I couldn't tell from the look.

Comment: @Nayana: I clicked the "edit" link below your post so I could see the details of your question as entered, then I just used my arrow keys to march my cursor through your code. Sometimes the cursor jumped, showing a tab character, and sometimes it moved space by space. It moved inconsistently, showing a mixture of tabs and spaces. I did not actually edit your question: I clicked the "cancel" link when done.